# why explicitly tell ajax to carry cookie when send cross-domain request still does not work?

Tags: ajax, cookies, cross-domain

My front-end colleague access his local app, and set hosts for it

```
127.0.0.1 my.foo.com
```

and meantime in the page he invokes back-end api which in my machine by ajax

```
$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: 'http://192.168.0.204:8080/bar/search',
    contentType : "application/json;charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    ...
```

because one is `my.foo.com` and another is `192.169.0.204:8080`, so back-end cannot receive cookie in this case, because it's cross-domain. So need explicitly tell ajax request to carry cookie in request header, at the same time server also need to do some configuration in response header, see below

```
client:  xhrFields: { withCredentials: true }
server: 
- Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
- Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://my.foo.com/
```

then I found server still could not receive cookie. I want to know why explicitly tell ajax to carry cookie does not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cookies are always scooped to a particular domain and are never sent to servers in other domains.

Allow-Origin doesn't change that fact.  It simply informs the browser to allow scripts on the named host to access the 192 host.  That doesn't imply cookies are shared, and as you've seen, they're not.

Your simplest solution would be to put both sites under one domain and scope the cookies to the shared domain.  Them both sites can read it.  You're making up the names anyway, so why not name both sides?

There are other technique of sharing data across domains, but they all involve you sending the data in some way other than cookie.